# How do I access a SQL Count result value in a LotusScript agent

Tags: sql, lotusscript

I have to run a SQL query and return a count and then pass that count back to a LotusScript function in order to place the value on a form.

The result from the SQL query

sqlStatement = select count(GMCPLN#A) as NumRecords  from [database] where (GER#<=3 and GER#<=3) AND GTRMDT = 0

returns

[image]

How do I now access the value of NumRecords in the LotusScript code?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a quick cut and paste of an agent I have coded that retrieves SQL data.  I've put your statement in and have set a print statement to show the result.  Hope this helps.

```
Options
Uselsx "*LSXODBC"

Sub Initialize

    Set con = New ODBCConnection()
    Set qry = New ODBCQuery()
    Set res = New ODBCResultSet()
    con.SilentMode = True

    If con.ConnectTo("DATABASE_NAME", "USER", "PASSWORD") Then
        Set qry.Connection = con
        Set res.Query = qry

        qry.SQL = {select count(GMCPLN#A) as NumRecords from [database] where (GER#<=3 and GER#<=3) AND GTRMDT = 0}

        If Not res.Execute Then
            Messagebox res.GetExtendedErrorMessage,48,res.GetErrorMessage
        Exit Sub
        End If

        Do
            res.NextRow

            Print "NumRecords = " + res.GetValue("NumRecords")      

        Loop Until res.IsEndOfData

        res.Close(DB_CLOSE)
        con.Disconnect      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can convert this to the code I have to work with

Comment: Couldn’t get it to match up so I did a count of a field and ran a loop to  simply count the results. Much easier to get up and running.